# How to format label in ASP.net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, reporting-services

I have created a column chart in asp.net. I am showing the date on x-axis. At the moment the date is shown as dd/mm/yyyy. All I need is to show the date as dd-mm-yy and ideally Weekday, dd-mm-yy e.g. Monday, 12-05-15.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="900px" BorderWidth = "1">           
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="uploaded_date"  YValueMembers="value"  ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Line" YValuesPerPoint="6" BorderWidth="6" >
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>


        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY Title="Quantity" TitleForeColor="#ff0000" Interval="20">
                    <MajorGrid Enabled ="true" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX Title="Date" IsLabelAutoFit="True" TitleForeColor="#ff0000">
                <MajorGrid Enabled ="False" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formatting:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd-MM-yy");
```

Output:

```
Montag, 15-06-15 //Written day of week in your local culture.
```

To edit the axis labeling, you can do it in your code-behind file:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dddd, dd-MM-yy";
```

Or in your markup:

```
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        <AxisX Title="Date" IsLabelAutoFit="True" TitleForeColor="#ff0000">
            <LabelStyle Format="dddd, dd-MM-yy" />
            <MajorGrid Enabled ="False" />
        </AxisX>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you just edit your question and paste your code into it? We can give you way more concrete answers, if you supply us with the right information.

Comment: Here is the html side

Comment: @Asbat I have edited my answer and shown you 2 ways on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

place this in aspx page(html side)

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrDate"/>
```

and use this in page_load at backend(cs file)

```
ltrDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd") + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
```

Comment: you're missing a `+` after the `,`

Comment: I am newbie, I am getting data from sql-server database for the series. Can you please tell me how to add the code in html5 / page.aspx?